# IIS Url Rewrite - Change QueryString / Hide QueryString

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I am quite new to this. Can someone please told me is this possible with the IIS URL Rewrite.

Let's say I have a url like below:

**www.abc.com/subfolder/test.aspx?id=xxxxxxxx**

I want to change it to something like this:

**www.abc.com/test.aspx**

OR

**www.abc.com/test.aspx?id=xxxxx**

If this is possible, can someone just give me an idea to start with?

Comment: What have you tried? The examples are quite clear https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module